# Stop session from expiring when browser closes

Tags: php, php-ini

It seems to be that my PHP session is expiring/deleting when the browser is closed.

Is there a way I can prevent this to happen ? Is it only a PHP setting or is there a browser say in this as well ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need:

- Change [session.cookie_lifetime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime) value
- Change [session.gc_maxlifetime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime) value so that it should not be lesser than cookie life time value. Otherwise your session cookie will point to invalid session storage

However, if you want your *session* to persist after browser was closed, it seems that it's not "session" by definition. I.e. technically, you can do that - but logically that seems to be architecture smell.

Comment: Thanks ! Did not know about the session.cookie_lifetime

Answer (score 3):

That is the behaviour of a **`session`** . If you don't want that to happen make use of **`Cookies`**.

Comment: Hmmm. Thanks. I think I have to.

Comment: But you can store **uncritical** data in Cookies which should be longer available then for the session lifetime.